# Wrong input symbols in recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, input-language

ubuntu 18.04
I'm trying to reset pass (for learning purpose) and impact with input-language problem in recovery mode. It ask: 
"Press Enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue)"

I try to press Ctrl+D but nothing happens, so I press Enter and PC wait for my input. When I type something instead of English symblos 'f' it prints Russian 'ф', for 'b' > 'б' looks lite transliterating. And I can't input anything in English.

I check /etc/default/[keyboard (screenshot_hete)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M33u0.png). But it looks like Ok.
Screen from GUI language settings[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBnyx.png). I can switch input lang with win+space when I logon.

ps: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/default/keyboard` you have:

```
XKBLAYOUT=us
XKBVARIANT=rus
```

which means that you have the *Russian (US, phonetic)* keyboard layout in the console.

To make it match your GUI settings, you probably want:

```
XKBLAYOUT=us,ru
XKBVARIANT=,
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but after applying your variant I steel can't type in English when I in recovery mode. Same thing happening 'л' instead of 'l' appears when I press 'l'

Comment: @AnatoliyD: Did you reboot after applying?

Comment: of course, anyway how can I get into recovery mode without reboot?)